# Elements take too much time to load in a popup div

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

Trying to scrape subscribers data from this page. https://happs.tv/@Pablo .This is exactly like the facebook's likes box, which opens when we click on likes on a post. I need to scroll inside the pop-up which shows all those who liked a post. That works. However, the issue is that after 3-4000 names, the new names start taking an awful amount of time to load, 40 seconds for a new name, sometimes. Even so, the script fails, doesn't exit because there is no `break` but then keeps repeating the same names. What could I improve to get past this. I tried increasing the driver wait, should I increase it more? Kind of stuck here.
Here is the part after the pop-up div with all the subscribers is open. Perhaps a better way to scroll inside the div? Could it be because of the `cache`?Just a stab in the dark.

```
current_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="userInfo"]/a'))
while True:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userInfo"]/a').send_keys(Keys.END)
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 35).until(lambda x: len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="userInfo"]/a')) > current_len)
        current_len = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="userInfo"]/a'))

    except TimeoutException:
        name_eles = [name_ele for name_ele in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="userInfo"]/a')]
        time.sleep(5)
        for name in name_eles:
            nt = name.text
            n_li = name.get_attribute('href')
            print(nt)
            print(n_li)
            dict1 = {"Given Name": nt, "URI": n_li}
            with open('happstv.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:
                w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
                if not header_added:
                    w.writeheader()
                    header_added = True
                w.writerow(dict1)
```

**INFO** :- Just changed the driver to Firefox, seems to be going better. Will update question details, if any issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. The response from an API should be less than 3s/request. If your request takes too much data, please load with "SELECT top 10". You should ask your team for performance first.
2. You can try FluentWait as

   ```
   driver = Firefox()

   driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")

   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10, poll_frequency=1, ignored_exceptions=[ElementNotVisibleException, ElementNotSelectableException])

   element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div")))
   ```